# Как подключится к серверу WoW? [C#]

Tags: c#

Вообщем интересует ответ на вопрос , который уже озвучен в заголовке треда. Возможно есть уже готовая реализация или же если подскажите в какую сторону копать , буду очень благодарен.Нужно для того чтобы проверять прокси на возможность аутентификации и коннекта на пиратских серверах ( 3.3.5 + )

Comment: Данный вопрос очень общий и специфичный. Объясню... Для авторизации на игровом сервере нужно отправить пакет по определенному протоколу, определенному порту и с определенной информацией (которая должна содержать данные пользователя, а еще как минимум протокол клиента и некую защитную "соль"). Если нет готовых решений или API, то что бы такое сделать надо знать приличное кол-во информации о спецификации сервера. Так что голосую за закрытие...

Answer (score 1):

Вы бы сначала изучили вопрос на предмет:

- наличия шифрования сетевого трафика;
- доступности информации по структуре пакетов;
- порядка авторизации;

Думаю стоит начать с изучения [open-source](https://github.com/mangoszero/server) разработок коммунити WoW.

Comment: Там помомему старая версия сервера, мне бы хотябы хоть какую-то инфу по поводу коннекта к серверу к 3.3.5а или же 7.3.5. Гуглер из меня походу фиговенький( Но Всё равно спасибо за инфу.